# Python maketrans() and translate() not working

Tags: python, string, methods, translate

Trying to utilize the Python string translate() and maketrans() methods for replacing a string. Yes, both strings are the same length. When I replace "Tuxedo" with "Serena"- it works. When I replace "Serena" with "Tuxedo"- I get "Texedo".

```
sailorsquad = str.maketrans("Serena","Tuxedo")
txt = "Serena"
txt.translate(sailorsquad)
'Texedo'
sailorsquad = str.maketrans("Tuxedo","Serena")
txt = "Tuxedo"
txt.translate(sailorsquad)
'Serena'
```

Also tried doing just txt.translate and it still does not work.

Comment: *Serena* has 2 *e*s, the second one (mapped to *e*) overrides the first one (mapped to *u*).

Comment: You have misunderstood how `maketrans()` works.  It does not translate _whole strings_, it translates _individual characters_.  And your specified translation contains two different mappings for "e".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Serena" has two e's, so when you you make a translation table from it with `e -> u` and `e -> e`, the last one wins:

```
>>> str.maketrans("Serena","Tuxedo") == str.maketrans("Srena", "Txedo")
True
```

In other words, 'e' still maps to 'e' in that transalation table:

```
>>> chr(str.maketrans("Serena","Tuxedo")[ord('e')])
'e'
```

The inverse, `Tuxedo -> Serena` works fine because the letters of "Tuxedo" are all unique.

If you're actually trying to replace whole words and not individual characters, perhaps you just want to simply use [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) instead:

```
>>> "Hello Serena".replace("Serena", "Tuxedo")
'Hello Tuxedo'
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess I misunderstood the method.